# Supremum in context of Dynamic Programming

Tags: recursion, supremum-and-infimum

In Bellman's *Dynamic Programming* (1957), regarding the equation,

$$ f(x) = \max_{0 \leq y \leq x} \left[ g(y) + h(x-y) + f(ay+b(x-y)) \right]$$

He writes [about extending this to an infinite recursion],

*... we may encounter many of the usual difficulties associated with infinite processes. It is, first of all, no longer clear that a maximum exists rather than a supremum. That is to say, there may be no allocation policy which actually yields the total return $f(x)$.*

I understand the definition of supremum requires two sets, $S$ and $X$, $S \subset X$. My question is, what are two sets in this particular context. More generally, is there a convention for when the sets are not mentioned explicitly?

Comment: I don't understand where the two sets you mention come from.  Can you elucidate?  Bellman's statement simply says, so far as I can see, that a real-valued needn't attain a maximum on a non-compact domain.  Perhaps there is some context missing?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what the supremum is over. The context is, he first describes finite recurrences (where a Max is used), now is introducing the infinite recurrence, and there needs to be a Sup instead of a Max. And I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Are $x$ and $y$ integer variables?

Comment: Nonnegative reals.

Comment: The maximum is over the set $\{0\leq y \leq x | y\in \mathbb{R}\}$  where $x$ is some fixed real number.  (Otherwise it doesn't make sense to me to talk about $f(x)).$  A priori there is no reason to believe that for some value of $y$ the maximum value of the right-hand side is actually attained.

Comment: By the last sentence, do you mean the right hand side may diverge? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: The intention is to find a general solution that is a function of $x$, $y(x)$, so that's how $x$ need not be fixed.

Comment: No, I don't mean that it diverges, in the sense that the supremum is infinite.  Suppose the supremum is $3$.  If the domain is compact (and the function continuous) then we know there is some point $x$ with $f(x)=3.$  But if the domain is not compact, there need not be such a point; then $f$ has a supremum, but not a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

The question is answered in *Dynamic Programming and Optimal Control* (Bertsekas, 2017):

$S = \left\{ f(x) | y \in \left[ 0, x \right] \right\}$

$X = \mathbb{R}$